DA2 Trimble Receiver and Field Maps Integration
I have a few questions.
I’m using a DA2 Trimble receiver with their correction service for accurate mapping (Trimble Catalyst, centimeter level). I want to send this data to Field Maps instead of Teraflex because using separate maps takes too much time to get the asset names.
The main reason I prefer Field Maps is that Teraflex does not allow me to add labels to a background layer. Another field team captures points with their phones while they do the maintenance of the assets, so I need to map them accurately and keep the same names used in our asset management app. So in Field Maps I just use a background layer with enabled Labels and it is very easy to type the same one during the data collection.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Tablet:

Mock Locations: Enabled on my device.
Bluetooth: Paired the receiver.

Trimble Manager:
Share Location: ON

Degree Notation: Decimal degrees
GNSS Correction Services: Auto
Output: GDA2020 (Australia)
Geoid: AUSGeoid2020 (Australia)



Antenna Height: Fixed at 2 meters

In Field Maps/ArcGIS Online, I have set up the following:

Feature Layer: Published in GDA2020
-I added the GPS Metadata Fields by using the Add GPS Metadata Fields tool in ArcGIS Pro.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-gps-metadata-fields.htm
Units: Metric
Coordinates: Automatic
Distance: Automatic
Area: Automatic
Provider: Integrated (if i change this it it showing only the phone
coordinates)
Antenna Height: 0 meters (since it’s already set in Trimble Manager)
Profile: GDA2020 7844



Map Coordinate System: 3857 (WGS 1984 Web Mercator)



Transformation: GDA2020_To_WGS_1984_2 (using that profile)


So far so good, Field Maps shows pretty much the same accuracy with Trimble Manager, for example 3cm horizontal in field manager, around 3cm in Field Maps. I used split screen and everything looks fine.
However, the problem is that the coordinates that are captured, come in decimal degrees instead of GDA2020 Cartesian.
Also, the height in Field Maps seems to be in ellipsoidal values, not from the Australian Height Datum.
The data I need must be imported into the system in GDA2020 (zone 56), and the height should be in AHD (Australian Height Datum).
Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong?
Is this a configuration issue, or is it just a limitation of what Esri can do?

7856 is GDA2020 MGA 56. 7844 is Geographic 2D, lat/lon.

I suggest you post this question on the Trimble Mapping and GIS Solutions Community.  You probably have to create an account (should be free) in order to post a query.
The Trimble Mobile Manager people watch that forum, and since large numbers of ESRI users have Trimble GNSS receivers, the TMM people have a good idea of how Fieldworks operates and what it can do.

Thanks. I found an answer regarding the height datum: Field Maps doesn’t support vertical datum transformations, so I’ll need to keep post-processing it. Unfortunately, none of the tools can handle the entire job in one place.
Here’s more info: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/field-maps/latest/prepare-maps/high-accuracy-data-collection.htm
